# Calculate Processing End Dates without Circular Error

Tags: excel, exception, excel-formula, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I have an excel sheet to calculate Processing Start Date and Processing End Start for a list of batches based on a daily Quota set for different time periods.

1. Processing Start Date for 1st batch: 15 June 2021.
2. Sundays are considered as non-working day.

To calculate Processing End Date, I divided Total tons to be processed by corresponding daily quota and added the resultant number to the Processing Start Date to obtain the Processing End Date.

On event, the result Processing End Date of a particular batch is not an integer which implies the daily quota is not achieved, the next batch is initiated the same day.

I am seeking for a formula to implement on the Excel Sheet which automatically takes into account the daily quota to calculate number of Processing Days, also the formula also takes into account quota changes between Processing Start Date and Processing End date if any without returning circular error.

The Excel Sheet is available on the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PsYYt-4XNHi2Cx4949A40plGsN5vxtUu/view?usp=sharing!

[image: Spreadsheet]

Comment: Many people here will not download files from unknown sources. It would be better to include sample/mock data directly in your question. That way it will be useful in the future even if the link goes dead. Can you also let us know what you've tried so far and how it fails to achieve the desired result?

Comment: In C3 `=IF(H2=INT(H2),I2+1,I2)` formula.. Since H2 is not an integer (most of the time).. How to we know the amount of the remaining Quota for Batch B on the last day of Batch A?